# No idea how to reproduce this gradient, any advice?

Tags: website-design, gradient, effects, illustrator-effects

Any idea how one would reproduce a similar effect? gradient but how, i have no idea

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kyle that seems the correct answer to me. Mind making it into one so I can upvote it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator- blue background rectangle under individual vertical rectangles with gradient fills in the long direction of each rectangle. Adjust and reposition gradient/ fill colors/ opacity for each long rectangle. In Illustrator study up on how to make gradients and come back with any specific questions or issues you may have.

[image]